# How to solve the differential equation with respect to $f(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let a not identically vanishing function $f(z)$ be analytic in $\mathbb{C}$ and such that $f(z + 1) = f(z)$ and $f(z + \tau) = e^{a} f(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\text{Im}\tau \neq 0$. The goal is to show that $a = 2 \pi i n \tau$ for some integer $n$.

I think the first step I may want to do is to show that $g(z) = f'(z)/f(z)$ is analytic

$$f′(z)/f(z) = N/(z-z_0)+ \text{analytic}$$

Then, I should prove that $g(z)$ is double-periodic

$$f'(z)/f(z)=f'(z+1)/f(z+1)$$

and then I'm stuck on how to solve the differential equation w.r.t. $f(z)$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2732640.

Comment: Or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1074745.