# Quasi periodic entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, quasiperiodic-function

This problem is exercise 6.1 from Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*.

> 6.1 Let $\Lambda=\mathbb{Z}\omega_1$+$\mathbb{Z}\omega_2$ be a lattice.Suppose $\theta(z)$ is an entire function,with the property that there are constants $a_1,a_2\in \mathbb{C}$ such that,$\theta(z+\omega_1)=a_1\theta(z)$ and $\theta(z+\omega_2)=a_2\theta(z)$.Show that there are constants $b,c\in\mathbb{C}$ such that,
> $$\theta(z)=be^{cz}$$

I've seen the answer in this [Proving a function to be exponential given that it satisfies certain equations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3483943/proving-a-function-to-be-exponential-given-that-it-satisfies-certain-equations).
But I do not think the answer there is right because the constant $B$ defined does not satisfy $e^{Bz+B\omega_1}=a_1e^{Bz}$
Can someone give me a hint on how to go about proving it?

Comment: If you think that an answer is wrong then you can leave a comment and ask the author for clarification.

Comment: Here is another (hopefully correct) solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4183695/42969

Comment: Another one, with a different approach: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2732640/42969

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the references.I've included my solution(in the edit) in an approach different from your answer.Please let me know if that's correct.

Comment: It looks correct to me. Your function $g$ is the derivative of the function $g$ in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2733062/42969 and is doubly-periodic, that makes it a bit simpler. – I would suggest that you post your solution as an answer to the older question. Then we can close this (and perhaps more questions) as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Done.I've added it to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2733062/42969.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\theta(z)$ is not identically $0$.Consider the function $g(z)=\theta'(z)/\theta(z)$.Clearly $g(z)$ is an elliptic function with periods $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ since $\theta'(z)$ is quasi-periodic with same quasi-periods.Let $P_0$ be the fundamental parallelogram of the lattice.Then,
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial P_0} g(z)=0$$
since the sum cancels out on the opposite sides of the parallelogram.But this is same as saying,
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial{P_0}}\frac{\theta'(z)}{\theta(z)}=0$$
which by the Argument principle is the number of zeros-number of poles of $\theta(z)$ in $P_0$.But $\theta(z)$ is an holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ meaning it has no poles in $P_0$.Hence,by the above equation it has no zeros as well.Hence $\theta(z)$ is a non-vanishing entire function.Thus,we have $g(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ and since it is an elliptic function,it is bounded.By Liouville's theorem it must be a constant,say $c$.Then,we have,$$\theta'(z)=c\theta(z)$$
and solving it we get
$$\theta(z)=be^{cz}$$.